# Retrieving data from multiple in memory dbcontext

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, domain-driven-design

Let's assume that I have following project structure:

> -SOLUTION
> | --> Read.User(Project)
> |   |--> Model
> |   |  |--> User.cs
> |   |--> DataAccess 
> |   |  |--> ReadUserContext.cs
> | --> Write.User(Project)
> |   |--> Model
> |   |  |--> User.cs
> |   |--> DataAccess 
> |   |  |--> WriteUserContext.cs

The following structure allows me to separate the Write models that does some changes to domain object from the read models that only gets the values from DB and, futhermore the **one more** important information is that, I cannot save Data using ReadonlyContext, all of the SaveChanges methods has override with NotImplementedException which I wont be changing due to protection level of our architecture.

I'm struggling with creating a test to the following architecture.

For now to use **InMemoryDatabase** which has some limitation that I have to overcome somehow.

Lets Assume the test should look like:

> 1. Creating Write Context with Factory
> 2. Add User to WriteDbContext Users DbSet
> 3. Save Changes on WriteDbContext
> 4. Creating Readonly Context with Factory
> 5. Retrive the all users from Users DbSet

The following example would return 0 Users. Why ?
Well firstly becouse it's InMemoryDatabase I had to provide The **InMemoryDatabaseRoot** to the both of DbContext to let them share the same data, but then I step into the biggest problem.

When I'm trying to Read data from ReadonlyDbContext I'm using Users DbSet that has been created from User class in the following project, however the User that I Added in second step of test and saved in on third had occured on Users DbSet that **uses User class in Write project**.

InMemoryDatabase recognizes those DbSets as separate "tables" when on Real Database they are one and the same table.

So I have question for you guys. Is there any way to do that on InMemoryDatabase or should I move to real database to create this kind of tests?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2022 Microsoft recommends using your production database engine rather than an in-memory double. I suggest you read the whole chapter on testing ef core applications for details :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/